# Recursively delete dependent rows in one single table oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, foreign-keys, recursive-query

For the standard ORACLE sql example table EMP, the schema contains EMPNO is primary key and MGR is the EMPNO for the current employee's direct manager (foreign key refers to the table itself).

Question1: How to write a recursive sql procedure to delete one manager and cursively delete all the people working under this manager 
 , including those who do not directly report to him or her?

Question2: Could this be done by deletion from a view created by repeated base tables?

Comment: IMO the "right" way to solve Question 1 is to define an ON DELETE trigger which handles deleting subordinates. YMMV.

Comment: You have a foreign key on `MGR`. So if you are going to recursively delete all employees under that manager, and what if any of those employees are themselves managers. wouldn't it fail with child record found constraint error?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with single delete statement.

You need to SELECT All employees in the hierarchy using `HIERARCHICAL` query then delete them.

e.g to Remove all employees under EMPNO `7566`(JONES) in the standard ORACLE sql example table `EMP`

```
DELETE FROM EMP WHERE EMPNO IN 
(SELECT EMPNO
FROM   EMP
CONNECT BY PRIOR EMPNO = MGR
START WITH   EMPNO=7566);
```

All the best :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible using **VIEW** based on the table and **INSTEAD OF DELETE ON** trigger on the view.

Create a view based on Employee Table

```
CREATE VIEW EMPLOYEE_VIEW AS SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES;
```

Create following Trigger on the view

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER EMPLOYEE_VIEW_DEL INSTEAD OF DELETE ON 
EMPLOYEE_VIEW 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE MANAGER_ID =:OLD.EMPLOYEE_ID;

END;
/
```

This should work , this will avoid the mutating table error ORA-04091 Mutating table error !

Peace!